# Cannot ping or SSH into new Catalyst 2960-CX switch from the server VLAN (1)

Tags: vlan, switching, ssh, management, switchport

I recently setup a Cisco Catalyst 2960-CX switch at work (I'm a SysAdmin at a SMB). Our workstations use VLAN 3, but our servers use VLAN 1. The management IP of the new switch (in VLAN 3) is 192.168.3.253

I can ping it and SSH to it from the workstation VLAN (VLAN 3), but not the server VLAN (VLAN 1). How can I fix this? We are using a ROAS ("router on a stick") setup for the VLANs. I can ping everything else to/from VLAN 1 to/from VLAN 3.

Here is the "show run brief" of the switch:

```
NewSwitch>ena
Password:
NewSwitch#show run bri
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2278 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 18:18:32 UTC Thu Jun 14 2018
! NVRAM config last updated at 17:59:56 UTC Thu Jun 14 2018
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname NewSwitch
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$GYaG$LSF2suD8FNQhzrM70mwg61
!
username admin password 0 ***********
username Equus password 0 ***********
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
ip domain-name company.local
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-3533827072
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-3533827072
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-3533827072
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-3533827072
 certificate self-signed 01
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
 switchport trunk native vlan 3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
 switchport trunk native vlan 3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
 switchport trunk native vlan 3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 192.168.3.253 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group INBOUND in
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.2.1
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
ip access-list extended INBOUND
 permit icmp any any echo
 permit icmp any any echo-reply
 permit tcp any any
ip access-list extended OUTBOUND
 permit icmp any any
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
line vty 0 4
 password ***********
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password ***********
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I inherited the network like this. I certainly agree you with you about not using VLAN 1 for servers!

Comment: Add a real ip subnet to vlan 1; it doesn't have an address right now. FWIW, it's often recommended not to use Vlan 1 for user / server network traffic (looks like I deleted my comment to reword about the time you responded... sorry for out of order comments).

Comment: @MikePennington, I added an IP for Vlan1 and it is pinging now, but I still don't seem to be able to SSH into the switch from Vlan1. Any ideas?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip default-gateway 192.168.2.1
```

It has no interface (or route) to 192.168.2.1, so *you have no default route*. Point your default-gateway to something that exists in 192.168.3.0/24 [vlan3].

Comment: It's a "configure terminal" command, I see now. However, it did not resolve the issue. Also, I am almost certain I had already applied this command.

Comment: This did not work.